# Login to Wordpress with Gatsby

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to make a static website using Wordpress and Gatsby everything works fine locally but when I try to use it on a staging site I get this error :

```
Path: /wp-json
The server response was "401 Unauthorized"
Inner exception message: "You are not currently logged in."

 ERROR #11321  PLUGIN
```

So is there a way to give Gatsby access to my Wordpress website using my credentials ?

My gatsby-config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {

  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {

        baseUrl: `web-staging.******.io`,

        protocol: `https`,

        hostingWPCOM: false,

        useACF: false,

      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Wordpress site is password protected then you can specify your credentials in `gatsby-config.js` (see below). This setup caters for HTTP Basic Authentication (see [plugin documentation](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/plugin-options.md#auth)). AFAIK if you don't have HTTP Basic Authentication on your Wordpress site then the content should be accessible without a username/password.

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        // Other configuration options.
        auth: {
          htaccess: {
            username: WORDPRESS_USERNAME,
            password: WORDPRESS_PASSWORD,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Also, have you installed the WPGraphQL and WPGatsby packages on your Wordpress site?

Answer (score -1):

See the [options](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/) for the plugin, specifically `auth`:

```
auth: {
  // If auth.user and auth.pass are filled, then the source plugin will be allowed
  // to access endpoints that are protected with .htaccess.
  htaccess_user: "your-htaccess-username",
  htaccess_pass: "your-htaccess-password",
```

Comment: Is there a solution without using htaccess ?